# Content of script in /etc/init.d/ deleted on restart

Tags: sysvinit

I created a script in /etc/init.d called hello that does some bash commands.  Sometimes when I restart the linux device (remove then reinstate power), the contents of my script get totally erased although the actual file is still there.  There is another script in there called nginx that came with the system and doesn't have this problem.

I am running a Emlid RTK gps that has a linux computer built in.

Answer (score 1):

You should not turn off the device taking off the power cord/battery; hence losing the contents of recently written files.

Try to use the official procedures to shut it down - power bottom or option in the menu; in the long term the device will be more stable.

Also if you have got the `sync` command, use it after writing your file.

Comment: Is that the cause of the file going blank though?

Comment: Most probably yes.

Comment: You have got to run something *before* shutdown. `sync` has been the standard for decades now. Have you got it?

Comment: Can't say I will get access to the device to run anything before power off can I make a script that runs sync when it starts up or periodically while power is on?

Comment: You can run `sync` manually after creating the script in init.d if you have the command. I do know neither the implementation nor the device to be of further help.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, Im not actually changing the script after the initial save so I save it and restart maybe 5x and it's there and on the 6th time it goes blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation, as I don't know anything about this product.

It's possible the entire filesystem has been overwritten.

In many embedded systems the running filesystem lives in RAM, and is populated from a compressed image in flash (or similar) during a cold boot.

Alternately a software update may have occurred, which involved replacing the filesystem with a downloaded image.

On such systems, user settings tend to be stored on a separate filesystem.